# Disable pylint message for a given module or directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, pylint

Is there a way to disable Pylint's `duplicate-code` message just for test files? All of the tests in our project are DAMP so the duplicated code is by design. I understand we can add `# pylint: disable=duplicate-code` throughout our tests, but would rather add some sort of rule that says all files under a `test/` folder will have this rule disabled. Is there a way to do this?

To be more specific, I'm looking for something different from a 'run it twice' solution (which is what I've already fallen back on).

Comment: not related to this question, but I do want to know is "DAMP" really a thing? just found a few random posts.

Comment: i think so? I only heard of it a few months ago, but it all seems to be related to testing. DRY = Don't repeat yourself. and DAMP = Descriptive and Meaningful Phrases. So basically, the tests we write are very repetitive, and that's on purpose.

Comment: This is the best post i've seen about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests

Comment: There is an [issue #618](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/618) which is [an ongoing effort of one of contributors](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/tree/per_dir_config). Contributions and help are more than welcome.

Comment: See also Pylint [issue #214](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/214) ("`duplicate-code` can't be disabled").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be achieved with pylint plugin and some hack.

Assume we have following directory structure:

```
 pylint_plugin.py
 app
 ├── __init__.py
 └── mod.py
 test
 ├── __init__.py
 └── mod.py
```

content of mod.py:

```
def f():
    1/0
```

content of pylint_plugin.py:

```
from astroid import MANAGER
from astroid import scoped_nodes


def register(linter):
    pass


def transform(mod):
    if 'test.' not in mod.name:
        return
    c = mod.stream().read()
    # change to the message-id you need
    c = b'# pylint: disable=pointless-statement\n' + c
    # pylint will read from `.file_bytes` attribute later when tokenization
    mod.file_bytes = c


MANAGER.register_transform(scoped_nodes.Module, transform)
```

without plugin, pylint will report:

```
************* Module tmp.exp_pylint.app.mod
W:  2, 4: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
************* Module tmp.exp_pylint.test.mod
W:  2, 4: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
```

with plugin loaded:

```
PYTHONPATH=. pylint -dC,R --load-plugins pylint_plugin app test
```

yields:

```
************* Module tmp.exp_pylint.app.mod
W:  2, 4: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
```

pylint read comments by tokenizing source file, this plugin [change file content on the fly](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/blob/astroid-1.5.3/astroid/scoped_nodes.py#L283-L289), to cheat pylint when [tokenization](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/pylint-1.7.4/pylint/utils.py#L126-L134).

Note that to simplify demonstration, here I constructed a "pointless-statement" warning, disable other types of message is trivial.

Comment: Turns out duplicate-code cannot be disabled per github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/214 ;-(

Comment: and a very minor issue is that this causes an off-by-one-error on other reported issues since a line was added to the beginning of the `test.` files

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus here we insert a comment at the first line, to act as a module level command, the caveat is if the real first line of your source file is a statement, it will "consumed" the inserted comment command, [see also](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/pylint-1.7.4/pylint/utils.py#L527-L591).

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus line-no in reports should be correct, checker works on AST, which is not changed, at least they are correct in my test.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus  if your first line is a comment or Docstring or blank, it will work as expected.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus as the Github issue you post pointed out, checkers/similar.py has a different code path, cannot be disabled with comments, so this answer is not helping unless pylint support this feature.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus I see, as checkers/similar.py re-read the whole file, rather than analyze on AST, line-no would be all have 1 extra offset.

Comment: Neat idea, but I cannot get your example to work with pylint 2.11.1 and python 3.9.5. If I manually copy the `# pylint: disable=...` comment into `test/mod.py`, then it works, but the plugin is not accomplishing this automatically

Comment: Really want this to work, but it doesn't for me in pylint 2.13.4. I've gone so far as to verify that the AsteroidManager.stream() bytes do have the pylint modeline at the top of the file, but for whatever reason, pylint ignores them.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`--disable` or `-d` message control flag](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#messages-control-options) that can be used to selectively disable messages when called. You could therefore disable this message for all files under the test folder by running pylint on those files from within the project folder:

```
pylint -d duplicate-code test/
```

I was able to verify that I can cut out specific messages from all files in the directory, although I was not getting duplicate code errors and so could not check for that message.

You could also put this into a script that you run from your project's main directory. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
pylint src/
pylint -d duplicate-code test/
```

Alternatively, you could add `# pylint: disable=duplicate-code` to the top of each of the files for which you want to exclude these messages. It looks like that is about as far as file-wise selective exclusion flags goes for pylint.

Comment: this looks like a 'run it twice' solution.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus you might be stuck there. I can't find anything in the docs about applying global rules to specific folders, so you may just have to write a script to run your tests in one go on all of your files with different rules defined for the test folder. This is, as far as I can tell, the only way to blanket ignore specific message types for an entire folder.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus I take that back. I might be on to something. Will update in a few.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus it looks like [per-file exclusion is unpopular with pylint devs](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/381), although there is [some support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656086/in-pylint-is-there-a-way-to-locally-disable-a-warning-and-then-undo-the-previous), but nothing, from what I can find, for excluding entire directories. It looks like you have to add `# pylint: disable=duplicate-code` to each of your files if you do not want to do it the way suggested here.

Comment: @Engineero, adding `# pylint: disable=duplicate-code` to the top of `.py` files has no effect. See Pylint [issue #214](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/214).