# How to disable pylint error when checking bash scripts files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have added some linux shell scripts to the python app, and this scripts will be invoked on virtual machines on azure. Then I have checked a project with linter. For other reasons I do not add shebang line to shell scripts files. How to force pylint to ignore below error:

```
In ./.../install_dependencies.sh line 1:
# pylint: disable=SC2148
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem. I need to ignore warning in bash file too! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure, but going through these previous questions can help:

[How do I disable a Pylint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning)

[Disable pylint message for a given module or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312047/disable-pylint-message-for-a-given-module-or-directory)

Comment: Ok, I will check adding configuration files.